# Connect erlang client to oracle

Tags: linux, oracle, erlang

Does anyone know how to connect to oracle from an erlang client in linux? I guess ODBC drivers are required.

Comment: keep scrollable cursors off with oracle. The odbc connect option `{scrollable_cursors, off}`.

Comment: Read the answer i have POSTED below, it should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Erlang documentation [ODBC is the way to go](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/databases.html).

There is an Erlang ODBC API which  "should run on all Unix dialects including Linux.... But currently it is only tested for Solaris, Windows 2000, Windows XP and NT".  [Find out more](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/odbc/odbc.pdf).

There are ODBC drivers for Linux.  If you're lucky your distro will already have one installed.  [Find out more](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html#linux_odbc_state).

Comment: really? Are there really no native DB drivers in Erlang?

Answer (score 0):

==== Answer may be very useful if on Windows, but may contain helpful info for Linux as well =====
Now, First of all, we need to download an oracle client or oracle Database itself and install it from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html. Oracle installs and creates a folder called `oracle` (on windows). Inside this folder, you will find its $HOME folder normally: `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1`. If you are on windows therefore, when you access the ODBC Configurations by reading this: http://ozinisle.blogspot.com/2011/10/configuring-odbc-connection-for-oracle.html then you will create a new `Data Source Name (DSN)`  of your choice. The steps roughly are as follows: 
1. Select System DSN
2. Create New Data Source
3. Scroll Down to select Oracle in OraDB{Vsn}_home1
4. Specify the Username (UID), Password
5. Note down the Driver name you have selected, Note down the Data Source Name you have entered.
6. Test the connection and make sure windows says that its fine.
Now, after this, we go to erlang side. Look at this module, its should kick start you in communicating with oracle.

```
-module(oracle_client).
-compile(export_all).

-define(CONNECT_OPTIONS,[
                {auto_commit,on},
                {scrollable_cursors, off}
            ]).
-define(CONNECT_STRING,"DSN=data_source;UID=uid;PWD=password;DRIVER=Oracle in OraDb10g_home1").

connect()->
    odbc:start(),
    try odbc:connect(?CONNECT_STRING,?CONNECT_OPTIONS) of
        {ok,ConnObject} -> {true,ConnObject};
        Any -> {error,Any}
    catch
        E:E2 -> {exception,{E,E2}}
    end.

send_sql(ConnObject, SQLQuery)-> odbc:sql_query(ConnObject, SQLQuery).
```

Erlang ODBC server must be running first. Erlang ODBC will ask you for a connection string and options. In the options first of all note that most Oracle drivers will need those scrollable cursors off. Then, in the connection string, you will be required to enter valid UID (username), password, DSN (Data source name) and the driver name, all these exactly the way you created the DSN in windows ODBC connection in the steps above.
That should be okay. Note that you should stick to oracle drivers them selves and avoid third party ODBC Oracle drivers. I have, from experience suffered from using other third party drivers because after say, 10 million connections, the driver starts asking for money/License and blocks your traffic from reaching oracle DB.
Let me know in case you get any challenges. The module above is a bit rough, do not use as is because its just a shell testing module, otherwise you will need say a gen_server which will hold the Connection Object so that other processing just keep communicating with it. As long as you are successful in setting up the Data Source Name with the installed Oracle DB or client on your machine, then this module will help you otherwise most challenges are in setting up the ODBC Connection.
=== Linux === 
For Linux, i guess you need to get odbc libraries like  [Easy Soft ODBC Drivers](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/interfaces/odbc/linux.html), or [UnixODBC](http://www.unixodbc.org/). Then try to set it up as we did with windows above, and then use the Erlang module i have provided above. It should still work. I am afraid i have always connected to oracle from Windows and NOT Linux due to many challenges in setting up and configuring ODBC libraries (give it a shot, you may be succesful in setting up Unix ODBC or Easy Soft ODBC libraries), Otherwise, the Erlang part of it is sorted out.